# How to add new attachinary image to an instance instead of replacing the whole array in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cloudinary

This might be a stupid question since I can't find it already asked here but I can't find a solution no matter how I tried.

I use Rails 5 with **Cloudinary** and **Attachinary** gems.

I have a model **`PointOfInterest`** with

```
has_attachments :photos, maximum: 3
```

Everything works fine if photos are uploaded at once (with `simple_form`). But I want my users to be able to upload photos sequentially ; for instance 1 photo at the creation of the `point_of_interest` and then add 2 more later on `edit`.

Unfortunately the `update` method deletes the attachments before saving the new input.

I ended up building an array with the old attachment and new one from the update and tried to overwrite the attachments:

```
@point_of_interest.photos = new_photoset
```

but I get a `Runtime error => Can't modify frozen hash`.

I also just realized my `new_photoset` array mixes `Attachinary::File` (previous image) and `Attachinary::File::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` (new image) so I'm pretty sure I'm not on the right track.

I tries many different approaches and I don't find the Attachinary docs very helpful. 
Or maybe I should investigate on the `jQuery-File-Upload` side?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: "Unfortunately the update method deletes the attachments before saving the new input" - you mean the newly added images or the previously stored one? Can you share your controllers? Might help understanding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you split the actions in two steps. Add to your model:

```
has_attachment :point_of_interest_picture
```

and then step one would be to have the user upload a picture, and step two would be to upload two or more pictures

Comment: Thanks @Tom. This is probably what I'm going to do. I put this aside for now and will come back to it.